# Distillery Release doesn't find "release_ctl" in custom command

Tags: elixir, distillery

I've created a custom command for my Distillery Release by following the instructions in the [README](https://github.com/bitwalker/distillery/blob/master/docs/guides/running_migrations.md#custom-command), but the script I've created cannot seem to find `release_ctl`.  I'm using Distillery 2.1.1

For example, the following script...

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

release_ctl --mfa "Elixir.IO.puts/1" --argv -- "$@"
```

...exits with an exit code of `1`.  To make it even simpler...

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

which release_ctl
```

...also exits w/ an exit code of `1`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This was a simple brainfart.  I was missing `eval`.  I should have been using...

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

release_ctl eval --mfa "Elixir.IO.puts/1" --argv -- "$@"
```